# HA Terminal Server (VDI)

Tags: azure, cloud, high-availability, rds, vdi

I need a some help with a #Cloud_project on the #Azure.
I want to create maximum high availability #Terminal_Server ( #VDI ) service.
Everything should be available, consistent and partition tolerance. (yeah, I know about the #CAP Theorem. Just as much as possible.

So, my goal is: every service role should be fault tolerance: 
* AD Domain Controller, via AD Controller server and AD Replica Controller server;
* SQL Database (for #HA services), via SQL Server AlwaysOn Group;
* RD Gateway, via NLB
* RD Connection Broker, via Failover Cluster feature
* RD Session Host, via Failover Cluster feature
* RD Virtual Host via multiple Hyper-V servers
* File Share for a user profile disk, user shares via Storage Servers with a Failover Cluster feature

Of course, a disk array for hosting SQL, RDVS,  UPD, file shares.
All parts should be easy scalable.

Perhaps you have the same experience and can give me some advises.

I want to know:
* will it be as stable as i think?
* what roles can I combine on a instance together?
* What a sufficiently reliable disk array I can use? Can I use only a Azure Storage for my purposes? Is it reliable?
* Should I fully trust to the Azure SQL service and don't implement my solution?
* Is it some service in the Azure instead of NLB or DNS round-robin?
* Can I use Azure Active Directory instead? How much it is secure and reliable?   Can I create different domains and GPO there?

## Windows_clustering

Thank you very much!
Best regards,
Anton